# Making multiple rows into one

Tags: mysql

I have looked through several similar questions, but cannot find exactly what I am trying to do.

I want to combine multiple rows into one, but conditionally choose values for each of the resultant rows.

### Test table:

[image]

### AnotherTest table:

[image]

I want to group Test table by SomeId e.g. group all 50s, 51s, 52s etc.
The resulting row should always use the Value from the row with SomeId = 1 and if there is a matching AnotherTable, it should have the the OneMoreId when TestTable.YetAnotherId = AnotherTest.YetAnotherId.
Additionally, it should select AnotherValue with following logic: if there are multiple rows with SomeId=2, the AnotherValue should equal 1234 -- unless all of the rows with SomeId=2 have the same value.

### Here would be the expected output

[image]

```
create table Test (SomeId int, AnotherId int, YetAnotherId int not null primary key, Value int,AnotherValue int)
insert into Test (SomeId, AnotherId, YetAnotherId, Value,AnotherValue) values (1,50,22,200,null), (2,50,23,50,55), (2,50,24,75,55)
insert into Test (SomeId, AnotherId, YetAnotherId, Value,AnotherValue) values (1,51,25,300,null), (2,51,26,50,66), (2,51,27,75,67)
insert into Test (SomeId, AnotherId, YetAnotherId, Value,AnotherValue) values (1,52,30,500,null), (2,52,31,50,77)



create table AnotherTest (YetAnotherId int, OneMoreId int)
  insert into AnotherTest (YetAnotherId, OneMoreId) values (25, 777), (31, 555)
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I believe that I provided everything except for effort. I only got as far as grouping Test with AnotherId, but did not know the syntax adding the conditions.

Comment: Please test code before posting.

Comment: ...and please clarify the PRIMARY KEY on both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're after something like this...

```
SELECT a.value
     , MAX(y.onemoreid) onemoreid  
  FROM test a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN test b 
    ON b.anotherid = a.anotherid 
  LEFT 
  JOIN anothertest y 
    ON y.yetanotherid = b.yetanotherid 
 WHERE a.someid = 1 
 GROUP 
    BY a.value;
```

Comment: this is what I needed, would not have thought to join test on test. Can you explain how the MAX function works in this case?

Comment: Replace MAX() with y.onemoreid. Replace GROUP BY with ORDER BY. Now you can see what the non-aggregated result looks like.

Comment: I added one more column to question, would greatly appreciate your output.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly but can you please check if joining tables will be your solution?

This will show every rows in test table and also one more id if it finds in another table.

```
  SELECT t.value,a.OneMoreId FROM test AS t 
  LEFT JOIN anothertest AS a ON a.YetAnotherId = t.YetAnotherId
```

If you only want to see if it finds in both tables. use inner join instead

```
  SELECT t.value,a.OneMoreId FROM test AS t 
  INNER JOIN anothertest AS a ON a.YetAnotherId = t.YetAnotherId
```

Note : you can remove "INNER" keyword as it's the default join.
Hope it helps

Update : this might work as you expected

```
SELECT mainTest.Value,(  
    SELECT a.OneMoreId FROM anothertest AS a 
    INNER JOIN test AS t ON t.YetAnotherId = a.YetAnotherId
    WHERE t.AnotherId= maintest.AnotherId)  AS OneMoreId
 FROM test AS mainTest
 GROUP BY AnotherId
```

Comment: I want to group all rows in Test by AnotherId and include AnotherTest.OneMoreId if there any matches for any row in that group.

Comment: Not sure if it works in all your situation but guess you can give it a try :)

Comment: this doesn't execute

Comment: Works well for me, any error do you see?
Maybe try to change the first line to  `SELECT mainTest.Value `...